# Save area of HTML5 canvas to image

Tags: jquery, html, image, canvas, save

I was wondering if it was possible to save an area of a canvas to a local image (so the user is promoted to download it or opens in new window) e.g.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfjZM.png

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  When you say "save an area of canvas" you can use the clipping parameters of drawImage to get a sub-area of a canvas.  When you say "save to local image" you can open a new browser tab with an image created from your canvas.  The user can right-click-save-as that image to save it to their local drive.

Comment: 1. That sounds like what I need, I basically want to save an area of a canvas e.g. position x,y with width and height like the image shows.     2. Is there no way to make it so the image is downloaded instead of opening in a new browser tab so the user has to save it                  Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course! To create a clip of the canvas do for example:

```
function getClip(x, y, width, height) {

    var ocanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        octx = ocanvas.getContext('2d');

    ocanvas.width  = width;
    ocanvas.height = height;

    octx.drawImage(mainCanvas, x, y, width, height    // source rectangle
                               0, 0, width, height);  // off-screen canvas

    return ocanvas.toDataURL();                       // return as data-uri
}
```

Now you could provide the data-uri as a href for an anchor tag with the download attribute set:

```
<a download="myFilename.png" id="downloadLink">Click here to download</a>
```

and in JS set the link dynamically:

```
document.getElementById('downloadLink').href = getClip(x, y, w, h);
// optionally set file name 'download' here as well
```

This works well in most browsers but not in IE though. But to utilize the download attribute where it is available you could check for its support by doing this:

```
function hasDownload() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    return (typeof a.download === 'string);
}
```

If no support perhaps create an overlay with the image and download instructions for IE users, or present image in a pop-up and so forth.

A simple example:

```
var link = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
link.href = getClip(x, y, w, h);

if (!hasDownload) {
    link.target = '_blank';
    link.innerHTML = 'RIGHT-CLICK and chose "Save image as" to download.';
}
```